# Which is faster.. Checking array or inserting into database everytime.?

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, database

I want to know which is faster and efficient for the following scenario.. I have a file like

"CS1 hello CS2 hi CS3 john

CS2 ram   CS4 boy CS1 sam

CS6 rahul CS1 kat CS2 hi"

Likewise I have `n` no. of lines with no order or any kind of arrangement.

I have Fields in database like CS1 CS2 CS3 CS4 and so on. I want to insert the values of the CS1 in its respective field in database and likewise for all fields.

I use String Tokenizer for separating the data.

I have two ideas:

1. Storing the `CS<no>` in a array and storing its values in another array by checking everytime (or 2-dimensional array), and then insert into database in one query.

or

2. insert into table for specific column everytime as I read the file.. like insert into table (`CS<no>`) values(`<data>`)
   Which is better one?

Comment: Use the *batch insert* API of JDBC. It will be fast and you won't need to maintain an auxiliary memory structure.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thanks that seems a good idea.. i ll get back to you soon once i test it.. and sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for 1), definitely better to have just one database transaction to insert all values. You could use a list of pairs (Cvalue, actualValue) in which you append values and then insert them to the database.